# glob - scan folder for php news article files

Tags: php, include, glob, scandir

I have a news overview page, and a folder of php files I would like to individually include.
Rather than manually including each one into my overview page, I thought I would use php to scan the folder for php files, and print them out as an include statement.

I have the following code:

```
<?php $articles = glob("/assets/news/form/*.php"); ?>
<?php
if(count($articles)) {
  natcasesort($articles);
  foreach($articles as $article) {
  ?>
      <?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/$article"); ?>

<?php
    }} else {
      echo "Sorry, no articles to display!";
    }
?>
```

I get no syntax with this, but I do not receive any output. Just a blank space where the articles should be.

The output I am wanting is something like this:

```
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/1.php"); ?>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/2.php"); ?>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/3.php"); ?>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/4.php"); ?>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/5.php"); ?>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview/6.php"); ?>
```

Ultimately I am wanting to write a php function that scans a folder in `ROOT/assets/news/form/`
for all php files, and include all the files with the same name from the folder `ROOT/assets/news/overview`.

My news overview page is currently in `/news/index.php`

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: "I thought I would use php to scan the folder for php files, and print them out as an include statement" - this is fine until you get an unwanted PHP file in your dir, then you would automatically include it. I would stick with manual includes or at least limit them to ones you know are good.

Comment: `echo file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: have you considered using a db, if these 'news' files are just text\html

Comment: This is a temporary solution and a db is far too much effort than it is worth! I am looking for an easy php solution...

Comment: `glob()` returns full pathnames, not just the filenames. So `$article` is something like `/assets/news/form/1.php`, and you're trying to include `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/overview//assets/news/form/1.php`

Comment: i have found a db is less effort than maintaining flat files

Comment: hmmm.. @Barmar I did not know that! and Dagon you are actually probably right to be fair. :/ It's a learning curve I think I will have to take pretty soonish..

Comment: Did you consider printing the filenames you were trying to include? If you're having a problem like this, isn't it normal debugging technique to view the data? It would then have been obvious what was going on.

Comment: I've tried debugging.. it's just a blank white space when I try and echo anything from it. I am sorry for my callowness with php! A week ago though, I didn't know what $_GET was! I am open to all advice. DB is a good shout from Dagon

Comment: @LukeCottingham Have a look at my answer below. I tested it my own server using `absolute` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here, give this a whirl:** (TESTED)

Tested on my server using `absolute` path.

```
<?php

// path to .php files must be absolute path
// example: /server/user/f/fred/forms/*.php
// May have to modify your path if it's not absolute

// You may have to use this, if doesn't work
// $articles = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/forms/*.php");
$articles = glob("/assets/news/forms/*.php");

if(count($articles)) {
  natcasesort($articles);
  // rsort($articles); // use rsort for descending order

foreach($articles as $article) {
    $article = basename($article);

// You may have to use this, if doesn't work
// include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/forms/$article");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/forms/$article");

      }

    }

else {

echo "Sorry, no articles.";

}

?>
```

Comment: With this I currently get the following error: Warning: natcasesort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in httpROOT/news/index.php on line 113

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in httpROOT/news/index.php on line 115

Comment: @LukeCottingham That's bizarre. It worked for me. Let me go double-check, but I'm pretty sure that's the exact syntax I used. Give me a minute.

Comment: @LukeCottingham Well this is the most BIZARRE thing. Upon testing what I posted, it worked perfectly. Now, all of a sudden, it's showing me multiple copies. I honestly don't know what happened all of a sudden. I'll try and rework it, and let you know.

Comment: @LukeCottingham Actually, scratch my last comment (above this one). It worked. It may be the way you set up your `path` in `glob("/assets/news/form/*.php");` - also make sure your script isn't in the same folder as your articles and to only have articles files inside it.

Comment: hmmm... well, if I run off localhost I just get the echo, and off server I get syntax. Really is bizzarre. I am presuming that syntax is telling me there are no files where it is looking.. so it is looking in the wrong place. Although, if I echo $articles to see what it is displaying, it doesn't display anything? Am I doing something wrong

Comment: @LukeCottingham If your path to the article files are `httpROOT/news/` then it should probably read as `glob("httpROOT/news/form/*.php");` or `glob("httpROOT/news/*.php");` if that's where the articles files reside in.

Comment: @LukeCottingham For example, on my server the (test articles .php files) were in my `/testfiles/` folder, but my code read as `glob("/var/user/f/fred/testfiles/*.php");`. So it must be a `path` syntax/issue, as to why you got the errors earlier.

Comment: sorry, the httpROOT was just a hide for the real root of my server files, (public_html) but all folders for cpanel etc..
I have tried a $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/form*.php is this the right format?

Comment: @LukeCottingham Ok, I understand. Well you see what I mean though, right? As for what you mentioned about `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/form*.php`, is that for the `include` line? If so, you should keep it as `include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/$article");`, give that a try and see. But ONLY if that's for the `include` part.

Comment: yes, the include part is that. As for the glo, I am just struggling to direct it to the correct folder! Why does my serv setup have to be so damn awkward! >:( Do you think a basename array might help?

Comment: @LukeCottingham For the array, I don't know. **Try this:** Change the 1st line to `$articles = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/*.php");` (assuming that's where the articles reside in), and then the **include** line to `include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/assets/news/$article");` - I tried that and it worked also for me.

Comment: thats got it!! :) I don't suppose you happen to know how to include in a descending order do you? rather than 1.php 2.php 3.php, it would be 3,2,1?

Comment: @LukeCottingham Great!! As for using an ascending order, I sure do; it's `rsort` instead of `natcasesort`.

Comment: Can I just employ you to teach me?! HAHA! That's got it.. everything solved AND in descending order! :) Thank you very much fred

Comment: @LukeCottingham LOL! I'm always open to new clients! Oh, I made a slight error in a previous comment. `rsort` is for **descending** order. And you're very much welcome Luke, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @LukeCottingham I am not a pro, but I do rather well for the projects I come up with and wish to achieve. S.O. is a good place to learn, and there are some good sites out there with good tutorials. I for one have used http://www.tizag.com/phpT/ and many others. It's a good place to start. Enjoy coding!

Comment: (Y) Haha.. I do actually have another issue if you are up for helping?? :) It is php again and to do with variables?

Comment: @LukeCottingham Sure, I'll see if I can help. Are you going to post a new question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32532/discussion-between-luke-cottingham-and-fred)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
```

to:

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
    $article = basename($article);
```

to strip off the directory prefix in the result of `glob()`.